# Substring and replace together?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, substring

I am new to T-SQL. I want to use `substring` and `replace` together, but it doesn't work as expected,
or maybe there is some extra function that I do not know.

I have a column that stores date time, and the format is like this : '1393/03/03'.

But I want to show it like this: '930303' , i.e. I want these characters '13' and '/' to be omitted.
I tried `substring` and `replace` but it does not work.

Here is my code :

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CreateDate,2,REPLACE(CreateDate,'/',''),8)
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the error?

Comment: Argument data type nvarchar is invalid for argument 3 of substring function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CreateDate,2,8),'/','')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `CONVERT` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Allows converting dates from one format to another, in this case, 111- JAPAN yyyy/mm/dd to 12 - ISO yymmdd

```
SELECT convert(NVARCHAR(50), GETDATE(), 12)

SELECT convert(NVARCHAR(50), CAST('1393/03/03' AS DATE), 12)
```

Comment: +1 for the best answer: I was just about to type this :)

Comment: Yes well, even if it's not the accepted answer, I hope someone finds it useful!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to test my solution:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE('1393/03/03','/',null),3,8)
```

and with your column it will be:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CreateDate,'/',null),3,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input column's data type is `DATETIME` or `DATETIME2` (or any DATE/TIME data types), then you should convert it to `VARCHAR`, then replace the `/` character. ([DATETIME format styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx))

If it is a string already (VARCHAR), then the below solution will do the trick.

```
DECLARE @X DATETIME2 = '1393/03/03' -- Example for DATE/TIME data type
DECLARE @Y VARCHAR(32) = '1393/03/03' -- Example for VARCHAR data type

SELECT
    @X
    , @Y
    , REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), @X, 11), '/', '') -- Japan style
    , CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), @X, 12) -- ISO style
    , REPLACE(STUFF(@Y, 1, 2, ''), '/', '')
```

**EDIT**

Please note that formatting is not for the database engine, do the formatting in the frontend application if possible.

**EDIT 2**
Your error is: `SELECT SUBSTRING(CreateDate,2,REPLACE(CreateDate,'/',''),8)`

`SUBSTRING` has 3 arguments:

- `expression` (character, binary, text, ntext, or image)
- `start` (bigint)
- `length` (bigint)

In your query there are 4 arguments and the third is a VARCHAR type. With your solution, the valid expressoin is: `SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CreateDate, '/', ''), 3, 6)` (if the CreateDate is VARCHAR or NVARCHAR. If it is DATETIME or DATETIME2, you should use the methods shown above.)

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(50) = '1393/03/03'

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(@STR,'/',''),3,LEN(@STR))`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Try `RIGHT` function

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(CreateDate,'/',''),6)
```